# ansible and expect problem

Tags: shell-script, shell, java, ansible

I want to use expect tools in bash script by ansible. first, step my shell script. Checking for `$JAVA_HOME` variable. I set `$JAVA_HOME` but in Ansible, I get an error.

My `env` for `$JAVA_HOME`:

```
[root@portal bin]# env | grep JAVA
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161
```

and my shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 1    
spawn /opt/install.sh

expect  "\[input\] Are you installing the application at the central data center? \[yes/no default: yes\]? \[yes\]\r"
send    "yes\r"

expect  "\[input\] What is the code of central data center \[default: 01\]? \[01\]\r"
send    "01\r"

expect  "What is ip or hostname of your server \[default: localhost\]? \[localhost\]\r"
send     "portal\r"
```

my playbook:

```
- name: --- run portal expect ---
  shell: |
    cd /opt/
    chmod +x portal
    ./portal
```

Finally Error in Ansible:

```
TASK [ansible-portal : --- run portal expect ---]
****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [portal]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cd /opt/installer/bin/\n chmod +x portal\n ./portal", "delta": "0:00:00.015509", "end": "2018-07-07 14:01:57.971794",
"msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2018-07-07 14:01:57.956285", "stderr": "send: spawn id exp6 not open\n    
while executing\n\"send    \"yes\\r\"\"\n    (file \"./portal\" line 8)", "stderr_lines": ["send: spawn id exp6 not open", "    
while executing", "\"send    \"yes\\r\"\"", "    (file \"./portal\" line 8)"], "stdout": "spawn /opt/installer/bin/install.sh\r\nChecking input tasks\r\nSetting 
ANT_HOME\r\nChecking Java\r\nError: No JAVA_HOME is set", "stdout_lines": 
["spawn /opt/installer/bin/install.sh", "Checking input tasks", "Setting ANT_HOME",
 "Checking Java", "Error: No JAVA_HOME is set"]}
```

There is no problem when running script as usual.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with setting up Ansible, but have you tried explicitly setting environment variables in your ansible file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733511/how-to-set-linux-environment-variables-with-ansible

Comment: java variable is true and i sure not problem. Because there is no problem when running script as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$JAVA_HOME` is set for your interactive shell, but when you're running your Ansible playbook, the shell you're running that in on the remote server, likely doesn't have `$JAVA_HOME` set.

Not a problem for Ansible though, simply set it as a argument when the task runs:

```
- name: --- run portal expect ---
  shell: |
    cd /opt/
    chmod +x portal
    ./portal
  environment:
    JAVA_HOME: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_161
```

#### References

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html

Comment: thanks @slm. this error solved. but I have another problem. in portal script i use `interact` and i want after the end of the questions, continue the script. But it stops.

Comment: @pyramid13 - if you have follow up questions it's best to ask them individually on the site. Mark this one as accepted and ask another question.